# Not getting a response when using Android Async HTTP (from loopj)

Tags: java, android, http

I am using the Async Http library from loopj.com and also the sample code from the site.

The problem is that when the request is made I don't get a response. I have even overridden the onFinish() function which isn't getting fire either.

I am using the sample code from their site which is as follows:

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

    Log.v("bopzy_debug", "Testing HTTP Connectivity");
    System.out.println("123");
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    client.get("http://www.google.com",
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    Log.v("bopzy_debug", response);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.v("bopzy_debug", "Finished..");
                }
            });
```

Any ideas on how to solve would be greatly appreciated, not really sure what is going on here.

Comment: Do you have internet permissions in your Manifest?

Comment: Nope. Thank you! Coming back from iOS so i'm only getting used to the Manifest again.. still feel rather stupid though. Post as an answer and i'll accept for you :)

Comment: Are you having trouble with POST/PUT requests?

Comment: I'm having trouble with PUT/DELETE requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your `AndroidManifest`

*Note: this needs to be added outside the `<application>` tag*